# firebase No static field IS_RESTRICTED_APPENGINE of type Z in class Lio/grpc/internal/GrpcUtil; or its superclasses Error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, grpc, dependency-management

While working on a project using GCP this time, after completing the code using Firebase, an error occurred while adding cloud Vision.
Thus, the dependency collision was prevented by exception handling, but another error occurred. The error contents are as follows.

[project Build.gradle]

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[app Build.gradle]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
packagingOptions{}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.voca"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'build-data.properties'
}
configurations {
    implementation.exclude module:'protolite-well-known-types'
    //implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-comon-protos'
    //implementation.exclude group:'com.google.guava'
    //implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-java'
    implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-javalite'
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:1.99.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.30.9')
implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.35.0')
//{OR}
//파이어 베이스
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.0')
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0')
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0')
implementation('com.google.capillary:lib-android:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
})
```

}

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.voca, PID: 24074
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (19.0.2).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$5(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:379)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$5.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field IS_RESTRICTED_APPENGINE of type Z in class Lio/grpc/internal/GrpcUtil; or its superclasses (declaration of 'io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil' appears in /data/app/com.example.voca-PC8_IVzX02rxZmfGRpj9gQ==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.createSslSocketFactory(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:451)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:418)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:513)
    at io.grpc.android.AndroidChannelBuilder.build(AndroidChannelBuilder.java:176)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:131)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:261)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:117)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$4(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:311)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$4.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:287)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

How can I handle this error? Please answer. :(

Comment: How are you using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0`? That [version doesn't exist](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages).

Comment: I don't know. Android studio showed me a warning and I fixed it to be the same as the build target. Could you let me know if there is another way

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `grpc-okhttp` is too old for the version of `grpc-core` being used. The versions should match.

You can see this by running `gradle dependencies --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath`:

```
...
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0 -> 19.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 -> 1.13.0
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-android:1.21.0
|    |    \--- io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.21.0] -> 1.28.1 (*)
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0
|    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.21.0] -> 1.28.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0 -> 2.7.5 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.21.0 -> 1.28.1 (*)
|    \--- io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.0 -> 1.28.1 (*)
...
```

So `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore` is pulling in `io.grpc:grpc-android:1.21.0` and `io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0`, but `io.grpc:grpc-core` is being upgraded from 1.21.0 to 1.28.1. The `[]` around `[1.21.0]` mean that the version *must* be `[1.21.0]`, but Gradle doesn't honor it.

The fix is to bump the version of `grpc-okhttp` (and `grpc-android`). There are two ways:

```
// individually
dependencies {
  implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-android:1.28.1'
  implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.28.1'
}

// or with a BOM
dependencies {
  implementation platform('io.grpc:grpc-bom:1.28.1')
}
```

Comment: oh god!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are my GOD..!! oh my goooooooooooooooood. Thank you :'-)

Comment: If an answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it (although you may not have enough reputation to do this yet). If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (which you can do, since you asked the question). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me for an issue with Google Cloud Translate API on Android too !

Comment: Thanks, it helps me for an issue with Google Photos Library API on Android too :>